# When Typing on my mac the cursor moves/deletes/replaces text

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Help! I don't know what is happening, with my computer (Macbook Black OSX 1ha0.6.6) but recently whenever I am typing my cursor suddenly moves in the middle of my frase or paragraph, deleting text, replacing words or just closing applications. I don't know what might be the cause but it's driving me crazy.

I have disabled typinator (which had worked fine for a couple of months) and looked through the keybindings in SystemPreferences>Keyboard>Keyboard Shortcuts. But for have not been able to find any answers. It happens in all apps that require typing. Textmate, Chrome, FIrefox, Texedit, Mail.

Does anybody know if there is a way I can review all keyboard shortcuts, to see if the issue lies there or any suggestions?

Thanking you dearly

Dave

Comment: does that have anything to do with your trackpad/touchpad, maybe disable it and use an external mouse? not sure but i'm making a guess.

Comment: There's a setting to disable the track pad when typing.  Try turning that on.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find the culprit, as I could not disable the track pad from system preferences. But I Did disable the click option. and so far I've had no issues. Thanks @rzlines & @Crhis Nava !

Answer (score 0):

Your battery has bulged and is causing the trackpad to misbehave. Replace the battery!